# Does search all sites work?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, search, stackexchange.com

For me, when on stackexchange.com I enter something into the `search all sites` box, the following page simply shows "Loading" in the content area. Is this just me or is it buggy?

Example: https://stackexchange.com/search?q=solver

Comment: Just you. Most likely Google is blocked on your side. (proxy, company rules etc). If you have Chrome check the Network tab in the JavaScript Console via the Tools and see for yourself.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I should have asked this on chat only. :$

Comment: Same problem here. I'm behind a enterprise firewall but the normal google search form is reachable. It would be great to search all sites, may be you should think about changing the global search page.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that Ghostery blocks "Google AJAX Search API". (Of course, in your case something else may be responsible, like a firewall.)

When it's blocked, the page appears to never load. Unblocking the "Google AJAX Search API" will allow it to load.

You can almost emulate the network wide search by using [`site:stackexchange.com`](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackexchange.com+solver). Some sites have their [own domain name](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248453/323179).