# Why do some Stack Exchange sites have their own domain names?

Tags: discussion, subdomains

I've found a strange thing: some Stack Exchange sites have their own domain names instead of `https://[site name].stackexchange.com`. The websites which have their own domain names are:

1. [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)
2. [Super User](https://superuser.com/)
3. [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)
4. [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)
5. [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/)
6. [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/)
7. [Seasoned Advice](https://seasonedadvice.com/)

Are there any parameters for allocating specific URLs to Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: Bravo for getting all the site names correct with their spacing! Not many people can do that.

Comment: related: [Can we have *.stackexchange.com aliases for sites that have their own domain names?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215071/997587)

Comment: Have wondered the same thing for a long time. Periodically I update my password for `*.stackexchange.com`, and I have my browser memorize the new password. I continue using the usual SE sites. Some months later I will want to post on Super User, realize that I have to go dig up the password or set a new one or whatever shenanigans being on a separate domain entails, and 9 times out of 10 I'll conclude that my question is either 1. not *that* important, 2. better asked on another site, 3. might be found by researching more, or 4. easier to ask on a (not ideal but) similar *enough* SE sub-site.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

It all started with three websites (created at different times), that are known as the "trilogy websites". These were created before Stack Exchange was official.

- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com)
- [Super User](https://superuser.com)
- [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com)

Some proposals were given new names once they launched.

- [Arqade](http://arqade.com) (also known as [Gaming.SE](https://gaming.stackexchange.com)) was renamed - [Stack Exchange blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/06/welcome-to-the-arqade/)
- [Seasoned Advice](http://seasonedadvice.com) (also known as [Cooking.SE](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/)) was renamed - [Related Meta Seasoned Advice question](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/824/is-this-site-going-to-become-seasoned-advice-if-so-when)
- [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com) (formerly [Ubuntu.SE](https://ubuntu.stackexchange.com)) was renamed in a partnership between Stack Exchange and Canonical - [Related blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/ubuntu-stack-exchange-is-askubuntu-com/)
- [Ask Different](http://askdifferent.com) (also known as [Apple.SE](https://apple.stackexchange.com)) was renamed - [Meta Ask Different post](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/205/official-site-title)
- [Cross Validated](http://crossvalidated.com) (also known as [Statistics.SE](https://statistics.stackexchange.com)) was renamed - [Meta Cross Validated question](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/489/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)
- [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com) (once known as [Nothing to Install](http://meta.nothingtoinstall.com)) was renamed - [Stack Exchange blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/)
- [Ask Patents](http://askpatents.com) (also known as [Patents.SE](https://patents.stackexchange.com)) was set up up [in coordination with the USPTO](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2013/07/22.html)
- [Answers OnStartups](http://answers.onstartups.com) was a failed experiment

Some were seeded from Stack Exchange 1.0 websites.

- [Money.SE](https://money.stackexchange.com) was seeded from the Stack Exchange 1.0 website [Basically Money](http://basicallymoney.com) - [related meta post](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/22480)
- [Electronics.SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com) was seeded from [Chip Hacker](http://chiphacker.com) - [related meta post](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/586/)
- [Sharepoint.SE](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com) was seeded from [SharePointOverflow](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27/the-broken-migration-process-is-broken-useful-sharepointoverflow-answers-are-r)
- [Mi Yodeya](http://mi.yodeya.com) (also known as [Judaism.SE](https://judaism.stackexchange.com)) was seeded from the original [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50/name-of-judaism-stackexchange-com)
- [SoundDesign.SE](https://sounddesign.stackexchange.com) was seeded from [Social Sound Design](http://socialsounddesign.com) - [related meta post](https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3)
- [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) was an original Stack Exchange 1.0 website - [related meta discussion](http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1416/)

Some were created (not seeded) from Stack Exchange 1.0 websites.

- [Homebrewing.SE](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com) was merged from [BrewAdvice](https://homebrew.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32/merger-with-brewadvice)
- [Skeptics.SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com) was merged from [SkepticExchange](http://skepticexchange.com), but [could not be seeded](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60/should-skeptic-exchange-be-seeded-with-questions-from-skepticexchange-org)

And a few proposals were seeded from non-Stack Exchange 1.0 websites.

- [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com) was seeded from [HashCode](http://hashcode.ru) - [HashCode meta post](http://meta.hashcode.ru/research/3747/%D1%85%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83-stack-exchange)
- [Русский язык](https://rus.stackexchange.com/) was seeded from [Русский язык on HashCode](http://russ.hashcode.ru) - [HashCode meta post](http://meta.hashcode.ru/research/3747/%D1%85%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83-stack-exchange)

There are also some domains used by Stack Exchange that are not for Q&A websites

- [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com) - This just holds applications that were created for use on Stack Exchange websites. While you *can ask questions*, the primary focus is on setting up applications.
- [Stack Auth](https://stackauth.com) - This domain handles the centralized authentication between all Stack Exchange websites.

The [API for getting the aliases](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites#pagesize=999&filter=!.UDMsw2*Hs-oA4de&run=true) was pointed out [in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3038224#3038224).

Comment: I'm sure there was also a discussion at some point about why they wouldn't be (obviously with potential exception) be 're-domaining' any of the existing sites any time soon.

Comment: @Pureferret [Domain Names: The Wrong Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/)

Comment: I'm pretty sure PPCG.SE can be accessed through alias by http://ppcg.lol

Comment: @OldBunny I'm pretty confident that's not owned by SE

Comment: What do you mean? It redirects to the real PPCG.SE

Comment: @OldBunny2800 the ppcg.lol domain is [owned by someone else](https://whois.uniregistry.net/whois?keyword=ppcg.lol) who has chosen to redirect it to PPCG SE. This answer only includes domains owned and operated by Stack Exchange.

Comment: hashcode meta post link is 404

Comment: What exactly does "seeded from Stack Exchange 1.0" mean? Does it mean it was just a continuation of the old community?

Comment: For communities which were "seeded", the existing questions and answers were brought over from the old communities into the newer Stack Exchange 2.0 communities. This distinction is important because not all communities could bring their content over (for various reasons).

Comment: Enlightening and a good read from the links above: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/05/domain-names-the-wrong-question/ `Don’t even think about the domain name!`

Comment: I was just about to ask about why do some sites have full domain names while other have site.stackexchange.com. I would have been downvoted and duplicated. Thank god for searching.

Answer (score 29):

- Stack Overflow, Super User, and Server Fault all predate Stack Exchange, meaning that they were created before the concept of Stack Exchange as network of sites existed; hence all three get to keep their original domain.
- The reason for [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) is covered in [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/ubuntu-stack-exchange-is-askubuntu-com/) by Jeff. In short, it's due to a partnership with Canonical Ltd.
- [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) also predates Stack Exchange as a network and was "assimilated" by Stack Exchange at some point; hence it keeps the domain.
- [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/) is not really a Q&A site, at least not in the same sense as all other Stack Exchange sites, hence it makes sense for it to have a different domain.

Comment: Just for competeness, what about the others like arqade.com, meta.nothingtoinstall.com (nothingtoinstall.com was retired) and seasonedadvice.com? Why are they special?

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett [Kevin did it now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/248474/152859). :)

Answer (score 13):

- [Mi Yodeya](http://mi.yodeya.com) (Judaism.SE) started as a [StackExchange 1.0](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/) community, and its founder chose to use the URL `mi.yodeya.com`. Because the community already had and liked the name when it [entered](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1/where-did-all-these-posts-come-from) the  StackExchange 2.0 network, StackExchange decided to make the name part of [its brand](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1045/design-for-mi-yodeya) when it launched out of beta.

Answer (score 13):

**Stack Overflow**, along with **Super User** and **Server Fault**, belong to the [Original Trilogy](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/the-stack-overflow-trilogy/). They don't use stackexchange.com because the Stack Exchange network hadn't been named at that point.

See also [What is the Stack Overflow "trilogy"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157006/176533), and ["Trilogy" in the SE Glossary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/40354/176533).