# API incorrectly lists mathoverflow.org among the aliases for MathOverflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, api

[This API query](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites#pagesize=999&filter=!.UDMsw2*Hs-oA4de&run=true) returns the aliases of various SE sites. For MathOverflow (with main domain mathoverflow.net) it returns

```
"aliases": [
        "http://mathoverflow.stackexchange.com",
        "http://mathoverflow.org",
        "http://mathoverflow.com"
      ],
```

But the second one, http://mathoverflow.org, does not function as an alias for the Q&A site; rather, it's a blog of MathOverflow, Inc.

(This came up in relation to [Why do some Stack Exchange sites have their own domain names?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248453/why-do-some-stack-exchange-sites-have-their-own-domain-names/))

Comment: I think the number of upvotes on this post exceeds the number of people who ever used the `aliases` property of `site` object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed:

```
{
  "aliases": [
    "http://mathoverflow.stackexchange.com",
    "http://mathoverflow.com"
  ],
  "name": "MathOverflow"
},
```