# Why do some sites end with '...Stack Exchange' but some don't?

Tags: discussion

Or why do all but one (I think there's only one...)?

All the sites I see end with 'Stack Exchange` on their logo's tooltip, site's welcome bar, etc... but Cross Validated doesn't - why is that? Are there any more sites without the suffix?

Examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248453/why-do-some-stack-exchange-sites-have-their-own-domain-names

Comment: @rene mildly related - but doesn't explain why some have `Stack Exchange` as a suffix and some don't - because some other sites that are a subdomain do have it...

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ: the explanation is the same. Some sites have specific branding. *Cross Validated* is a brand name, not a topic.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ: the SciFi Stack Exchange doesn't have a brand name. *Cross Validated* could be the *Statistics Stack Exchange*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ahhh - ok, sorry - didn't think of it like that - I guess you can use your 'gold power' to mark this as a dupe then? :)