# Can't see gold badge symbol on Android

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web, android, dupehammer

I recently asked a question and it was closed as a dupe by a gold badge holder - but I cannot see this on my Android phone in Google Chrome - is this a bug or my phone's problem?

[image]

As you can see in the image above, `Lance Roberts` doesn't have a gold badge symbol, but [he should](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252318/why-do-some-sites-end-with-stack-exchange-but-some-dont):

[image]