# Is there a list of all Stack Exchange sites that advertise themselves with Community Ads on other sites?

Tags: support, advertising, community-promotion-ads

I know that some Stack Exchange sites (e.g. Writing) have community ads that they submit on other sites (example below). Is there a list of all such SE sites? I assume based on past questions that there isn't a list of all community ads. I am looking for a list (not necessarily comprehensive), of all SE sites with these promotional community ads. Quoting @Catija "sites that create community ads for themselves and post them on other sites' metas."

[image]

Comment: So, there's two sides to this - first, the sites that host these ads - all "graduated" sites are able to host community ads ([for example](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17302/community-promotion-ads-2019))... second, sites that create community ads for themselves and post them on other sites' metas... that list is ... going to be difficult to create. Which is it you want?

Comment: @Catija Good point! Either would be fine. I prefer the second, but I understand the difficulties in making such a list.

Comment: I originally understood your question backwards, but I think I've managed to write another SEDE query for your intended purpose, see below.

Comment: That's very generous of you, but let me do some additional research first to make sure the query covers everything. It assumes a very specific format of the post (which is typical of Community Ads), if somebody manages to deviate the query might miss the instance.

Comment: I've now updated the query and found a few more instances.

Comment: Thanks to all users for the edits that have significantly improved an originally ambiguous question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I originally understood your question backwards, but [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuildingme/query/1054097/sites-mentioned-in-community-ads-answers-posted-in-year-x?year=2019) is a SEDE query which tries to extract the links to sites. Only direct links to sites count, like [this one](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7067/8732) in the example you mentioned. There are currently 27 sites doing this, some on multiple sister sites:

[image]

To make sure all links are considered (sometimes, they use a trailing slash, [sometimes not](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1587/30354); some links are still [HTTP instead of HTTPS](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12299/44520)), I've wrote [another SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuildingme/query/1054446/all-community-ads-links?year=2019) which lists all links and [another one](https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuildingme/query/1054434/community-ads-not-satisfying-the-format) for the few ads which don't satisfy the format.

---

If you just want to browse all [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) posts of a certain year, 
[here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1053894/community-ads-questions-posted-in-year-x?year=2019) is a cross-database SEDE query listing all questions.

[image]

SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday morning, but that should be sufficient for this specific purpose.

Comment: That query doesn't look too bad. You are lucky the format to expect is rather strict.

Comment: Otherwise I wouldn't even try (with SEDE; maybe the API + some custom logic would work).

Answer (score 4):

You can easily get a list of all community ad answers that link to Stack Exchange sites via several global searches:

- [`url:stackexchange.com [community-ads] is:a`](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Astackexchange.com+%5Bcommunity-ads%5D+is%3Aa)
- [`url:stackoverflow.com [community-ads] is:a`](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Astackoverflow.com+%5Bcommunity-ads%5D+is%3Aa)
- etc., with [other domains](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248453/323179).

You can cut down the number of results shown in these searches by adding `title:2019`, which will only return the current ads or `score:6..`, which will only return the ads which have enough score to actually be shown as ads.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Looks like it will be a long process to get a complete list.